# Making a custom list of Kinect Data for later assignment

Tags: panel

I am adding Kinect data capture into a MakeHuman Blender add-in, through a small .dll I have written.  I am getting data (JSON text) fine, which I hope is close to being correct.

The REALLY great thing is KinectV2's can capture up to 6 bodies at a time.  To take best advantage of that, I am trying to delay actually making the action(s) when the person hits the 'Stop' button.

Instead, I want the data for however many bodies were just tracked stored somewhere, and a list of what just got recorded displayed.  An 'Assign' button below it creates the action for the selected animation buffer on the selected armature.

The number of examples of using UIList on web is pretty small.  Many just point to existing Blender data.  My data also does not extend the data of any Blender types.  I see those calls to template_list where the same value is supplied for multiple arguments, and I am just totally lost.

Here is the current UI, with a mock-up of what I want to add in red.  Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I found my answer myself through trial and error.  Not every question is destined for re-use.  Feel free to toss.